# Is it possible to use tbl_regression fonction with lmer fonction with random effect?

Tags: gtsummary

I work on antifungal activity of some molecules ("cyclo") added with fungicides and I want to assess impact of these cyclos and their concentration ratio. CMI is a quantitative variable and all other variables are factors.

I have this script:

```
mod=lmer(CMI ~ cyclo*ratio + (1|fungicide) + (1|strains), data)
```

And I'd like to know if I can use `tbl_regression()` (`library(gtsummary)`) with my `lmer()`?

If yes, what do I have to specify for exponentiate term ? 
If I write `exponentiate=FALSE` I obtain the same values than the estimates in the classical `summary(mod)`.

Thank you for your help

Steffi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for `tbl_regression()` for a mixed-effects models is to print the fixed-effects only. To see the full output, including the random components, you need to override the default function for tidying up the model results using the `tidy_fun=` argument.

```r
library(gtsummary)

lme4::lmer(age ~ marker + (1|grade), trial) %>%
  tbl_regression(
    # set the tidying function to broom.mixed::tidy to show random effects
    tidy_fun = broom.mixed::tidy,
  )
```

[image]

You can use the `label=` argument to update the label displayed for the random components if you wish.

The default is `exponentiate = FALSE`, so you don't need specify in the `tbl_regression()` call.

For more details on the `tidy_fun=` argument, you can review this help file: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/vetted_models.html

Hope this helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you very much !! To be sure, are sd_Observation the stand dev for Residuals ?

Comment: Yep! That is correct.  You can run `broom.mixed::tidy()` on your model for a few more details about the output.